# Do I need OV or EV code signing certificate when packaging a classic desktop application for the Windows Store?

Tags: code-signing, desktop-bridge

I want to add a desktop (WPF) application to the Windows Store using the Desktop Bridge (MakePri, MakeAppx). I have tested my build process using a self-sign certificate and all is well.

However, I cannot find any information stating whether I need an Extended Validation (EV) certificate or if an Organization validated (OV) certificate is sufficient.  I know an OV certificate can cause SmartScreen warnings for installer .msi packages.

I also found old links (relating to Windows 8 apps) which say that the store does not use SmartScreen. But I cannot find anything relating to Windows 10 desktop apps packaged via the Desktop Bridge.

Will an OV certificate cause SmartScreen warnings when my converted application is downloaded from the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a valid certificate to publish your app to the Store. You just need to sign it with a test certificate. When you upload it to dev. center, it will be signed by Microsoft to be distributed through the Store.

I couldn't find a documentation that clarifies this, just saying it by my own experience. There are some notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-debug):

> To test your app in a realistic setting as you prepare for
>   distribution, it's best to sign your app and then install it.
>
> Visual Studio signs your app by using a test certificate. You'll find
>   that certificate in the output folder that the Create App Packages
>   wizard generates. The certificate file has the .cer extension and
>   you'll have to install that certificate into the Trusted Root
>   Certification Authorities store on the PC that you want to test your
>   app on.

Also if you use the new update of Visual Studio, you can create Desktop Bridge apps and publish them to the Store entirely through Visual Studio using the Windows Application Package project. It means you don't need to manually pack and sign it, VS does it for you.

**Edit**

Your users do not see an Smart Screen anyways. It makes sense since your app cannot run with administrator privileges. If your app needs a functionality that requires admin privileges, you need to consider it before moving forward.

Comment: So, that means that publisher validation is via a validated DevCert account not a certificate. That makes sense.

Comment: @SholaOgundeHome Yes. Check out my edit about admin privileges, it may affect you.

Answer (score 0):

According to Windows App Store's latest publish policy in 2023

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/store-policies

> The binary and all of its Portable Executable (PE) files must be
> digitally signed with a code signing

However, it's not clear whether a Standard (OV or IV) or an EV code signing certificate is required. I tried to query Microsoft with email about this but the staff just copy-and-paste the above linked content as a response.

I'll update more detail once I acquire the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).